# how to edit property paper size, layout, margin in window print by javascript

Tags: javascript, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7hHI.png)

how to edit property paper size, layout, margin in window print by javascript. I want print option paper size

Comment: What you do try so far?

Comment: Have you looked at the W3 documentation? https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#size

Comment: i read it and make but It dont' solution my problem